# I get an error when using selenium chromedriver to create a session where I am logged into my account

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver

The code I'm using start the session doesn't seem to be working, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

I can create a session without logging in and do what I want but when I try to the use the recommended method of creating the driver with an Options object and adding a user-data-dir, I run into errors.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)

driver.get("https://login.tripleseat.com/")
email_field = driver["login"]
email_field.send_keys("clshaps93@gmail.com")
email_field.submit
```

I want my program to get to the bottom section signed into my account without running into an error.

If I don't have a Chrome window already open, I end up with this error:

1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in`assert_ok': unknown error: cannot determine loading status (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
from no such execution context

If I do have Chrome window already open, I end up with this error:

1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in`assert_ok': unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Other values I have tried to use for user-data-dir just end up being ignored, in that a session starts without logging me in. Is there some code I need to add somewhere to avoid these errors?

Comment: After running the program, a new window appears where I seem to be logged in, but then I get an error at the line with driver.get().

Comment: What is this `driver["login"]`. There is no such syntax.

Comment: I got the syntax from here: (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/3.141.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver#[]-instance_method)

Comment: I think my problem had to do with me still having the chromedriver running in the background. What would be ideal though, is if I didn't have to close all my Chrome windows every time I want to run Selenium.

Comment: Okay, give me some time, I will check and you know what's the problem once I reach office. Buy why don't you use WATIR? WATIR is the wrapper around ruby selenium binding.